# Convert latitude, longitude and zoomLevel to latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, latitude-longitude

I have a zoom level `zoom=Z` and a position `latitude=x`, `longitude=y`, but I need to set the region with `latitude`, `longitude`, `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`.

I have found the image

[image]

to explain how `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` works, as well as the formula

```
zoom = Math.round(Math.log(360 / region.longitudeDelta) / Math.LN2
```

But how can I convert the zoom level `zoom=Z` to `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`?

I would guess that I only need to set either `latitudeDelta` or `longitudeDelta` and then calculate the other value from the screen size?

Answer (score 4):

So having your formula for the `zoom` dependent on the `longitudeDelta` we can express the 
`longitudeDelta` with some basic math rules:

[image]

This way we convert the `zoom` to `longitudeDelta`.
To find the `latitudeDelta` there are different ways. I prefer to find the coefficient between the `longitudeDelta` and the `latitudeDelta`, which will always be the same no matter the zoom level. Here is the sample code I wrote. I omitted the rounding for the zoom level to integer to show that the calculation are correct.

```
// Initial values
var latitudeDelta = 0.004757;
var longitudeDelta = 0.006866; 

var coef = latitudeDelta / longitudeDelta; // always the same no matter your zoom

// Find zoom level
var zoomLvlCalculated = calcZoom(longitudeDelta);
console.log(zoomLvlCalculated); // 15.678167523696594

// Find longitudeDelta based on the found zoom  
var longitudeDeltaCalculated = calcLongitudeDelta(zoomLvlCalculated);
console.log(calcLongitudeDelta(zoomLvlCalculated));// 0.006865999999999988 which is the same like the initial longitudeDelta, if we omit the floating point calc difference

// Find the latitudeDelta with the coefficient
var latitudeDeltaCalculated = longitudeDeltaCalculated * coef;
console.log(latitudeDeltaCalculated); //0.004756999999999992 which is the same like the initial latitudeDelta, if we omit the floating point calc difference

function calcZoom(longitudeDelta) {
    // Omit rounding intentionally for the example
    return Math.log(360 / longitudeDelta) / Math.LN2;
}

function calcLongitudeDelta(zoom) {
    var power = Math.log2(360) - zoom;
    return Math.pow(2, power);
}
```

P.S. Since Internet Explorer does not have support for log with base 2 you can use this formula to calculate with different base (e):

[image]

Comment: I thought that zoom levels would have corresponding latitude and longitude deltas constants. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but you can get the latDelta and longDelta from Region prop passed from onRegionChange();

```
const [latDelta, setlatDelta] = useState('');  //latitudeDelta stored in latDelta
const [lngDelta, setlngDelta] = useState('');  //longitudeDelta stored in lngDelta


const getCoordinates = (Region) => {
  
  setlatDelta(Region.latitudeDelta);  //store varable into latDelta
  setLngDelta(Region.longitudeDelta); //store variable into lngDelta

} 

<MapView>
  onRegionChange = {(Region) => getCoordinates(Region);}
</MapView>
```